# PowerShell/VBScript - Extract Outlook Mails Based on Condition

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Is there a way to obtain list of all sent & received emails having suffix **not equal to** `@gmail.com` via PowerShell or VBScript and possibly store it in seperate text files.

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type] 
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderSentMail)
$folder.items | Select-Object -Property Subject, SentOn, To
```

I was using the above PS to obtain sent mail, but not sure where to apply the condition.
Secondly, the subject is not appearing completely, it becomes `.....` is there any way to obtain the full subject as well ?

Comment: If you were to export the data the whole subject would be there. It's just powershell trying to fit the data on the console. Piping to `Format-Table -auto` can help for the console output. As for the sender my items dont contain the address but the friendly name of my contact so I am unable to filter with that data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running on a client computer not a server.  If you've access to the exchange server there's powershell commandlets that are easy to use (New-MailboxExport).

$folder is a COM-Object
$folder.items property contains a collection of COM-Objects representing messages.

Since they're objects, you can use the object commands (`Get-Help Object`) to use their properties.  You just need to dig a little more to apply your filter.  Specifically one more level, to the properties of the items in $folder.items.  Pipe $folder.items to Get-Member to get the full list of properties.  `$folder.items | gm`.  To, From, SentOn and Subject are all there.

```
$NonGmailMessages = $folder.items | 
 where-object { { $_.to -notcontains "gmail.com" } -and 
 { $_.from -notcontains "gmail.com" } }
```

One way of handling collections like this is to do one massive filter like I just did.  Or you can filter by stages.

```
$NonGmailMessages = $folder.items
$NonGmailMessages = $NonGmailMessages | where-object { { $_.to -notcontains "gmail.com" }
$NonGmailMessages = $NonGmailMessages | where-object { { $_.from -notcontains "gmail.com" }
```

Add further lines to further narrow your collection.

You can export this collection complete with all properties intact to a CSV:

```
$NonGmailMessages | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\nonGmailMessages.csv
```

Or you can narrow the number of properties exported

```
$NonGmailMessages | Select-Object -Property From, To, SentOn, Subject | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\nonGmailMessages.csv
```

`-NoTypeInformation` prevents the object type information from being listed at the start of the file.  This will make it a more 'pure' CSV for use in PS or Excel or whatever.  Plus the CSV IS a text based file format, as you wished.

Comment: Thanks, thats basically what i wanted. But, facing problems with filtering, there isn't any domain in `To` and `From` isnt an actual object. `To` just contains the name. 
Example : 
Mail sent to `abc.xyz@mno.com`, `To` shows as `xyz,abc` not the domain.
And is there any way to check all the folders of outlook ? Inbox, SentItems, Draft, Outbox etc

Comment: @Lastwish, I am unfamiliar with the com-objects you've used, so I do not know how to navigate the Outlook folders or to do any kind of recursion in them.  In Powershell, there are sometimes more properties that can be pulled from an object than the ones pulled by default.  I would pipe an item to the `Get-Member` command to explore the available properties.